# How to have nested command groups use the same name for the same level of subcommands but different implementation in click?

Tags: python, python-click

I am using click 8.0.3

I'm reading this https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/commands/#merging-multi-commands but I am still stumped.

### What I want

i want to be able to have this

```
cli cli1 new
```

and

```
cli cli2 new
```

### What i tried

i copy the same code in the link above

```
import click

@click.group()
def cli1():
    pass

@cli1.command()
def cmd1():
    """Command on cli1"""

@click.group()
def cli2():
    pass

@cli2.command()
def cmd2():
    """Command on cli2"""

cli = click.CommandCollection(sources=[cli1, cli2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

but i don't know how to add separate `def new` functions within each command group cli1 and cli2 and so that each `def new` can display as `new` but with different implementations.

I also don't want cmd1 and cmd2 to be on same level. I want such that the cli to work in this way where the separate group of cli1 and cli2 are lazily loaded.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working with the following code. Basically, create a top level `cli` group, and two nested groups that'll be added as commands, `cli1` and `cli2`. Defining the methods is easy enough, as can be seen by `new_cli1` and `new_cli2`. By default, click sources the command name from the method name, but you do have the option of customising that by passing in the name to the `command` method explicitly, as we've done here.

Although, you can use the `CommandCollection` provided by click rather than explicitly adding `cli1` and `cli2`. Not sure about the lazy loading, however.

```py
@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@click.group()
def cli1():
    pass


@cli1.command('new')
def new_cli1():
    print('cli1 > new')


@click.group()
def cli2():
    pass


@cli2.command('new')
def new_cli2():
    print('cli2 > new')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli.add_command(cli1)
    cli.add_command(cli2)
    cli()
```

Answer (score -2):

[Afterburner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71139884/14033765) is good. I just wanted to suggest you, if your code may grow more than those 20 lines, to separate each group in its own module. It is easier to maintain and you won't have such problems any more :)